# why its returning the "undefined" instead of 1

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, The below question should return 1 according to my knowledge about javascript, but it's returning "undefined".
could anyone tell me why it's not returning 1?

```
 var foo = {
    bar: function() { return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
  };
  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
  })(foo.bar);
```

Comment: Because `this`  inside `foo.bar` refers to the global object. There is no global variable `baz` hence `this.baz` is `undefined`. Learn more about how `this` works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this, [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196). Besides, it would never ever return `1` because [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns the *type* of a value. `1` is not a type.

Comment: "should return 1", no. It 'should' return `"number"`, if `this` is `foo`: `return typeof arguments[0].apply(foo);`

Comment: See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you invoke a function with `.` operator, then the object to the left of `.` becomes the context of invocation, which is `this`. But when you pass your function to another one as an argument, you lose the context, since you call it directly. If you want to preserve the context you can use `bind`.

```
(function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
})(foo.bar.bind(foo));
```

And, yeah, your function actually returns the type of `baz`, not the value itself. Remove `typeof` if you want to see `1`.

Answer (score 1):

> why its returning the “undefined” instead of 1

Because the way you call the function, `this` inside `foo.bar` refers to the *global object* (i.e. `window`). There is no global variable `baz` hence `this.baz` (`window.baz`) is `undefined`.
Learn more about how `this` works here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)

---

Besides, it would never ever return `1` because [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns the *type* of a value. `1` is not a type. At best it would return `"number"`:

```js
console.log(typeof 1);
console.log(typeof undefined);
```

To learn how to control the value of `this`, have a look at the links above and at [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) .